# How to send api key in Header @ Postman?

Tags: api, http-headers, postman

Iam trying to send Api Key in Header instead of Url .

When I tried to send Key with api it works good in Following way:-

http://api.mydomain.com?key=dsjfh

Screen Follows :- 
[image]

Is it Possible to send Key as Header ?

I tried something like this which is not working.

Comment: If the objective is to get it out of the query string then you could POST the request instead of using GET

Comment: @ Scrowler - Actually this is  Authorization Key for all CRUD Operations

Comment: Have you examined the headers in your final request data to ensure your key is there?

Comment: yes i did But Not there .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put the key in as a header it should in fact show up.  Here's an example below with a header called test with a value test.  As you can see in Fidler my request is indeed sent with the test header.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can send the header "x-api-key" :
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'll be sharing what worked with me.

Go to `Authorization`, choose as the type `API Key`, enter the `Key` and `Value`.

For me the key was `Authorization` and the value was `Basic X` where the `X` is the said key.

Answer (score 0):

Some APIs (like RallyAPI - rallydev) uses `zsessionid` param header for storing apikey value